# Broken link on the blog

Tags: bug, broken-link, blog

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/?cb=1

gave me this link to report the problem. The link has changed to

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-on/

Comment: You could correct it yourself and make a pull request :) https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/blob/master/_posts/2015-04-15-two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-on.markdown

Comment: OK, I made a [simple one here](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/pull/222), but I don't know a) how to test it, b) whether there was an underlying cause, or c) how your link has a /blob/master directory when there isn't any directory like that at https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/ . But I'm trying to help.

Comment: @Noumenon on the [first page](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog) you can find near the end how to setup a local version of the blog. After seeing your PR I'm wondering what the actual issue you ran into. Where does it link to that full url?

Comment: @rene Getting that running on Windows was not easy... thank you for showing me how to test.
The link was a bookmark, don't know where I found it.   
My pull request just tried to copy the redirect syntax in the YAML front matter block from `2008-04-30-logo-design-contest-winner.markdown`. However, that redirect does not work in the test environment anyway: visiting `localhost:4000/2008/04/logo-design-contest-winner/` does not work, even though `https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/logo-design-contest-winner/` does.

Comment: @rene I see that the post titles are generated by `permalink: /:year/:month/:title/` . Nothing about alternate URLs. I looked at the git history of `2015-04-15-two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-on.markdown` and it seems like it has always had the truncated title, so I'm stumped for now. Any ideas?

Comment: The actual problem might be an url encoding issues in the blog-engine it self. The url slug of the title should continue/include the single quote of `one's` as well. I'm not sure if that is fixeable in the github repo. Might need a dev to fix.